# Recolor a BMP image in canvas pattern

Tags: javascript, canvas, bmp

This code is being used to create a special pattern overlays for an OpenLayers map. I understand that the second color is replacing white with white but the code coming from out data feed has that in it so I include it in my sample.

Current working Code

```
const symbol = {
  kind: 'Icon',
  image:'', // base64 encoded image.
  colors:[
    {
      "oldColor" : [ 0, 0, 0, 100 ],
      "newColor" : [ 64, 101, 235, 100 ]
    },
    {
      "oldColor" : [ 255, 255, 255, 100 ] ,
      "newColor" : [ 255, 255, 255, 100 ]
    }
  ]
};

if (symbol.kind === 'Icon') {

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const img = new Image();
  img.src = symbol.image;

  img.onload = () => {
    const pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    symbol.color = pattern;
    delete symbol.image;
  }

}
```

I was reading about how you can manipulate pixels by color if you use drawImage but I am unable to determine how to implement this for the code above.

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// get the pixel data
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) { // we are jumping every 4 values of RGBA for every pixel
  symbol.colors.forEach(el => {
    if(data[i]==el.oldColor[0] && data[i+1]==el.oldColor[1] && data[i+2]==el.oldColor[2]){
      data[i]=el.newColor[0];
      data[i+1]=el.newColor[1];
      data[i+2]=el.newColor[2];
    }
  });
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I would expect this to work.  Does the if condition pass?

Comment: I altered the code that I included but I am unsure how to use implement it into the pattern.